# How to pass arguments to Python script in Alfred Workflows

Tags: python, alfred

I am trying to pass the `{query}` parameter to my python script (python newbie) so I can create a really simply calculation.

Heres what the workflow looks like:
[image]

My python script looks like this:

```
query="{query}"

x = float(query)/60

y = x*100

print "%.2f" % x, "%.2f" % y
```

However when I run it my debug returns this error:

```
[2018-10-13 21:56:25][ERROR: action.script]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Imran/Library/Caches/com.runningwithcrayons.Alfred-3/Workflow Scripts/A4A451B6-E747-4D1C-A957-431E755787A5", line 3, in <module>
    x = float(query)/60
ValueError: could not convert string to float: {query}
```

How can I resolve this? I want to be able to run `bill 30` to return a percentage calculation for me.

Comment: it should be the value `30`

Comment: Please review the tags assigned to this question, the `query` variable is one that is automatically inserted into the python script (starter code) by Alfred.

Comment: Yeah, but python is seeing the encoding, not the value.  There's a templating or pre-processing step that's missing.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the language you have two options in your `Run Script` object: `with input as argv` and `with input as {query}`.

If you have the first option selected your code should be this:

```py
import sys

query = sys.argv[1]

x = float(query)/60

y = x*100

print "%.2f" % x, "%.2f" % y
```

In the second case your code should be this:

```py
import sys

query = "{query}"

x = float(query)/60

y = x*100

print "%.2f" % x, "%.2f" % y
```

Comment: What does `sys.stdout.write(query)` do here?

Comment: @JRiggles I really don't know if it made any sense at the time of writing but I removed the line as it doesn't seem to make sense today.